# Gaps above and below panels in KDE Plasma

Tags: kde, 18.04, kde5

How to remove transparent 1px-height lines above and the panel in Plasma 5 (Ubuntu)? The background picture is visible through it and it looks crappy. These lines are appearing in any theme and any panel size.

[image: Gaps above and below panels]

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug that has since been fixed in KDE Frameworks 5.48.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=389215

As a workaround, you can turn compositing on.

Comment: Yes, this line disappears after update, thank you!